# Вывод таблицы в табличной ячейке html

Tags: php, html, table

есть вот такой код

```
<table>
<tr>
   <th>N</th>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Description</th>
   <th>LoginUserId</th>
   <th>StatusDevice</th>
   <th>NumOfLines</th>
   <th>StatusLine</th>
   <th>DirectoryNumber</th>
   <th>Protocol</th>
   <th>ActiveLoadID</th>
   <th>InactiveLoadID</th>
   <th>DownloadStatus</th>
   <th>CTI</th>
   <th>IPAddress</th>
</tr>

$array_root = $array_response['Body']['selectCmDeviceResponse']['selectCmDeviceReturn']['SelectCmDeviceResult']['CmNodes']['item'];
  $array_devices = $array_root['CmDevices']['item'];

  $i = 1;
     foreach ($array_devices as $value) {
        echo "<tr>\n";
        echo "<td>{$i}</td>\n";
        echo "<td>{$value['Name']}</td>\n";
        echo "<td>{$value['Description']}</td>\n";
        echo "<td>{$value['LoginUserId']}</td>\n";
        echo "<td>{$value['Status']}</td>\n";
        echo "<td>{$value['NumOfLines']}</td>\n";
        if ($value['NumOfLines'] !== '1') {
           foreach ($value['LinesStatus']['item'] as $state) {      
              echo "<td><table>\n";            
              echo "<tr><td>40$state[DirectoryNumber]</td></tr>\n";
              echo "<tr><td>$state[Status]</td></tr>\n";
              echo "</table></td>\n";
           }               
        } else {
           echo "<td>40{$value['LinesStatus']['item']['DirectoryNumber']}</td>\n";
           echo "<td>{$value['LinesStatus']['item']['Status']}</td>\n";
        }
        echo "<td>{$value['Protocol']}</td>\n";
        echo "<td>{$value['ActiveLoadID']}</td>\n";
        echo "<td>{$value['InactiveLoadID']}</td>\n";
        echo "<td>{$value['DownloadStatus']}</td>\n";
        echo "<td>{$value['IsCtiControllable']}</td>\n";
        echo "<td>{$value['IPAddress']['item']['IP']}</td>\n";
        $i++;
     }
  }
```

Если переменная $value['NumOfLines'] == '1', то все хорошо выводится в таблицу, потому что значение в этом случае имет тип Строка. Если $value['NumOfLines'] !== '1' то у меня начинаются проблемы с вставкой значений в таблицу (тип Array). Должно быть значения $state[DirectoryNumber] в столбце DirectoryNumber как таблица в ячейке, тоже самое $state[Status] в столбце StatusLine. А получается что один проход foreache валит $state[DirectoryNumber] и $state[Status] в первый столбец, а второй проход во второй столбец, то есть в столбцах получается пара $state[DirectoryNumber] + $state[Status].  А должна быть пара из 2-х (вообще понятно, что если итераций foreache ... as $state три то из трех) $state[DirectoryNumber] в первом столбце и пара из 2-х $state[Status] в другом. Надеюсь понятно написал (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Плохо, что без примера входных данных и ожидаемого результата, но насколько я понял, вам надо так:

```
if ($value['NumOfLines'] !== '1') {
           echo "<td><table>\n";            
                   foreach ($value['LinesStatus']['item'] as $state) {      
           echo "<tr><td>40$state[DirectoryNumber]</td></tr>\n";
           }               
           echo "</table></td><td><table>\n";
           foreach ($value['LinesStatus']['item'] as $state) {      
              echo "<tr><td>$state[Status]</td></tr>\n";
           }               
           echo "</table></td>\n";
        } else {
           echo "<td>40{$value['LinesStatus']['item']['DirectoryNumber']}</td>\n";
           echo "<td>{$value['LinesStatus']['item']['Status']}</td>\n";
        }
```

Если строк больше одной то в ячейках DirectoryNumber и Status будет создаваться по таблице в каждой, и заполнятся данными. Тут может сбиваться форматирование, если строки должны быть строго напротив друг друга, то при маленькой ширине столбца строки могут разъехаться из-за переносов.
Либо такой вариант:

```
        if ($value['NumOfLines'] !== '1') {
           echo "<td colspan='2'><table>\n";            
           foreach ($value['LinesStatus']['item'] as $state) {      
              echo "<tr><td>40$state[DirectoryNumber]</td>\n";
              echo "<td>$state[Status]</td></tr>\n";
           }               
           echo "</table></td>\n";
        } else {
           echo "<td>40{$value['LinesStatus']['item']['DirectoryNumber']}</td>\n";
           echo "<td>{$value['LinesStatus']['item']['Status']}</td>\n";
        }
```

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ. Первый вариант подошел идеально, это именно то что нужно. Я примерно так тоже пробовал, но запутался в выводе тэгов. Во втором вы тоже правы, слетает форматирование и надо заниматься подгонкой.